# On the definition of symmetric rearrangement

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For a measurable function $u:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{C}$ one usually defines the symmetric rearrangement $u^{*}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{+}$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
  u^{*}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{\{|u(x)|>t\}^{*}}dt
\end{equation*}
where for a measurable subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ one defines $A^{*}$ as the open ball with center 0 and volume equal to the measure of $A$.

This definition runs into trouble if some superlevel set $A=\{x:|u(x)|>a\}$ of $u$ has infinite measure. In this case one should define $A^{*}=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and still the definition of $u^{*}$ makes sense, but all information on the values of $u$ where $|u(x)|\le a$ is lost. Thus many prefer to define $u^{*}$ only for functions $u$ `vanishing at infinity', that is, having all superlevel sets of finite measure.

But there is no actual harm in defining, and working with $u^{*}$ also in the general case. The resulting function $u^{*}(x)$ is still radially decreasing but $\not\to0$ as $|x|\to \infty$. Essential properties remain true, although they may become trivial (e.g. both $u$ and $u^*$ have $L^p$ norm equal to infinity).

Am I missing something? and is there some serious obstruction in doing so, or is it only a matter of tradition to restrict the definition of $u^{*}$ to functions vanishing at infinity?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach works. I think the only thing one should be careful about is
$$
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f (|u^*|) =   \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f (|u|), 
$$
which can fail for example if $f(t)=(1 -t^2)^2$.

Comment: However if $f$ is nondecreasing and smooth the identity holds